# How do I create a POINTER to the Structure being defined?

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list, structure, ctypes

I'm writing a Python wrapper around [`getifaddrs()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getifaddrs/). The interface uses the `struct ifaddrs` type, the first field of which is a pointer to another `struct ifaddrs`.

```
struct ifaddrs {
    struct ifaddrs *ifa_next;   /* Pointer to the next structure.  */
    ... /* SNIP!!11 */
};
```

However, representing this in Python:

```
class struct_ifaddrs(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('ifa_next', POINTER(struct_ifaddrs)),]
```

Gives this error:

```
matt@stanley:~/src/pydlnadms$ ./getifaddrs.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./getifaddrs.py", line 58, in <module>
    class struct_ifaddrs(Structure):
  File "./getifaddrs.py", line 61, in struct_ifaddrs
    ('ifa_next', POINTER(struct_ifaddrs)),
NameError: name 'struct_ifaddrs' is not defined
```

`struct_ifaddrs` will not be bound to the current scope until the class definition is completed. Of course being a pointer type, it's obvious that the definition of `struct_ifaddrs` isn't required during declaration just as in C, but the type needs to be deref'd during later use. How can I proceed?

Comment: Is it feasible to take a small step back and implement the wrapper a little less literally? I'm thinking something like making your wrapper class look more like an array or list of `ifaddrs` without any notion of `next`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
class struct_ifaddrs(Structure):
    pass
struct_ifaddrs._fields_ = [
    ('ifa_next', POINTER(struct_ifaddrs)),]
```

As Paul McGuire notes in the comments, this is documented as standard solution for this problem in [the ctypes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#incomplete-types) and [yet another time in the same docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._fields_).

Comment: This exact problem is described in the ctypes docs, with this as the standard solution.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: A link to this could have won the solution.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Can you add a link to the description of this in ctypes for a +1?

Comment: @David Heffernan: But I feel cheated modifying people's answers on my own question. I won't upvote for that.

Comment: @Matt - Sven had already done the heavy lifting, I don't need to poach people's rep points. :)